# tsx cannot find module 'xxx'

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, tsx, yarn-v2

I am using yarn v2 to install the dependency package, and using `yarn start` command to start the project smoothly, but vscode always reminds me that I can't find any local modules.

[image]

And here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `@yarnpkg/sdks` package (which is a part of Yarn 2+)

You can enable PnP support in VS Code via:
`yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`
This will generate `tssdk` and modifies your `.vscode/settings.json` to add TypeScript compiler-wrapper inside `tssdk` as a Workspace TypeScript compiler. You should run VS Code, open any TypeScript file and in the bottom right side of the window click on TypeScript version. Select `Use Workspace Version` from dropdown menu to actually use Workspace Compiler, its version has the suffix `-sdk`.

You can also read Yarn 2+ docs regarding VSCode integration here:
https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks#vscode

Comment: Thank you! The `Use Workspace Version` was the piece I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

What the default [Nest.js installation](https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps#setup) `nest new project-name` does is uses yarn's [`nodeLinker`](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#nodeLinker) by creating a `.yarnrc.yml` in the project root:

```yaml
nodeLinker: node-modules
```

You can add this file to an existing yarn project, then run `yarn` and it will generate a `node_modules` directory that will make VSCode happy again.